# In a fork() the execl doesn't return to parent

Tags: c, unix, fork, argv

Here is my 1st file :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

printf("\n\nJe suis dans le fils\n\n");

execl("/exec","ii",NULL);

printf("\n\nJe suis revenu dans le fils\n\n");
}
```

And here is the exec file :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

printf("\n\n\n\nJe suis dans le exec\n\n\n\n");
printf("\n\n argc = %d \n\n argv[0] = %s \n\n argv[1] = %s",argc,argv[0],argv[1]);

}
```

The problem :

I'm blocked in the exec file, so the `printf` after my `execl`, in the 1s file, doesn't show :/
And also when I do the printf of argv[0] normally it should show me the file path but here it shows me "ii"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Note that your `execl` (a) executes a program in the root directory, which you should never do (don't work in the root directory, which only root should be able to write to, and do not practice programming as root unless you really like restoring from backups and have good backups to restore from), and (b) passes it just one argument, `"ii"`, which will be given as `argv[0]` to the executed program.  Maybe you want `execl("/exec", "/exec", "ii", (char *)NULL);` passing two arguments to your program. `exec` is a shell built-in too.

Comment: Very tempted to edit the title and remove the reference to "fork", but instead I'll simply ask:  where is the fork?  There is no fork implied by execl, and perhaps this is the source of your confusion.  If you want to fork, you must do so explicitly.

Comment: OT: It should be: `execl("/exec", "ii", (char *) NULL);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm block in the exec file, so the printf after my execl, in the 1s
>   file, doesn't show

That's right, `execl` doesn't return (unless there's an error). Once you `exec` there's no going back: in effect your process turns itself into another one, executing a different program.

> when I do the printf of argv[0] normally it should show me the file
>   path but here it shows me "ii"

Well as you figured out `argv[0]` shouldn't be taken for granted. The parent process can specify whatever it wants in it (even omit it). In your case *you* specify `argv[0]` for the child as `ii`. If you want to set it correctly (whatever that may be), add a second `"/exec"`.

---

Side note: if you want an easy way to execute something, you might want to look into the standard `system(3)` and `popen(3)` functions.

Comment: ok so if the execl() doesn't returns to the parent, do you know wich exec() function returns to the parents ?

Comment: @shubha No exec function returns to the parent.

Comment: Oo Is there a simple way to return to the parent ?

Comment: `system` is harmful and should never be used, for many reasons. `popen` is dangerous (shell escaping issues) but *can* be used safely with some care, and it's useful. `posix_spawn` is a bit harder to use, but much more flexible and safer.

Comment: @R.. I think you are over-reacting.  There are reasons to be cautious about how you use `system()` or `popen()`, but there are reasons to be cautious with most POSIX functions, and the `system()` and `popen()` functions used carefully are safe enough.  And suggesting `posix_spawn()` is not kind; that is a most horribly complicated function to use — even worse than `scanf()`.

Comment: @R, Jonathan I actually didn't think about security and argument sanitization. I just "guessed" what the OP was trying to do and went with the "easiest" thing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `system` is not thread-safe, and modifies global process state in a way that interferes with signal handling. I think this is reason enough to say it should never be used.

Comment: No; it is reason enough to say that 'if you are using threads, you should probably avoid `system()`' The POSIX specification for [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) specifies that it need not be thread-safe, and also specifies that it dinks with SIGINT, SIGQUIT and SIGCHLD signals. Clearly, if that's a problem to your code, you should not use it. Interestingly, `popen()` has none of those caveats. It is important to know the specification of what you're using. It is not always wrong to use it — most of my programs are still single-threaded.

Comment: In the code from the question, there is no reason to fear `system()`; there is no signal handling or multithreadedness.  In multi-threaded programs, there are reasons not to use it, but writing your own equivalent has its own set of problems (roughly, the problems that `system()` ducks for multi-threading).